# Is it OK to use "these them"?

Tags: word-usage

I see this sentence:

> To use these them, you just need to embed a bit of javascript in the
>   header of your site.

in this page: https://www.battleforthenet.com/july12/#participants

Is the use of "these them" OK here? A bit strange to me...
Probably there is no grammar problem, but is this used often?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a typo: it should be either **these** or **them**, but you can't have both. **them** is probably the better choice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a typo.

Comment: @JavaLatte But that's just the question. How could a person learn that it was a typo instead of good English to be emulated if they couldn't ask?

Comment: I think the writer intended to put "To use these *then*,"

Comment: @LukeSawczak: it's fine to ask, but it is only relevant to this particular OP: it's not general enough to be useful to other visitors to the site.

Comment: @LawrenceC: possible, but I think it's more likely that they could not decide whether to use **these** or **them**, and accidentally included both. **them** probably works best, as it reoccurs in the next sentence.  "To use **them**, you just need to embed a bit of javascript in the header of your site. Click here to try **them** out"

Comment: @LukeSawczak If there was real concern that "these them" might be acceptable, some additional research (added to the question) regarding such usage might resolve the issue.

Comment: @JavaLatte Fair enough. Typos can sometimes be instructive, though. Admittedly this one isn't very common (though the phenomenon of remaining signs of a changed mind is very common in hasty copy!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch. There certainly *is* a grammar problem.

If we tried to approach that phrase, "these them", we would probably try to analyze "these" as a demonstrative determiner because it's followed by a noun phrase — much liken "these cats".

But a demonstrative can never be followed by a *pronoun*, like "them". That is, you can't have "these them" any more than "this you" or "that me".<sup>1</sup>

Why is that? Because a pronoun is used to pick out a specific thing already. If you say "them", you already have just one group in mind, and you can't break the group down any further.

---

As a side note, your instinct to question this phrase was right. How do errors like this arise?

As an editor, I often see remnants of the author's train of thought. They frequently change a word, or hesitate between two words. And the don't always remember to clean up their other choice.

In that sentence, either word would have been okay on its own. If you kept only one, it would be a demonstrative pronoun. When that's the case, "them" is often preferred over "these", perhaps because "these" has that second role as a demonstrative determiner. That could lead to a reader parsing it incorrectly if they read it too quickly (because they might expect a noun after "these").

But to be clear, "these" or "them" would each be correct and would refer to the same thing. But "these them" can never occur in a proper English sentence.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> You can say that to mean "this *version of* you", etc, but that isn't standard and "you" would be treated like a common noun.</sub>

Comment: Your detail about these vs. them is good, but it doesn't answer the actual question (Is using *these them* OK?). The question is really about the accurate proofreading of a written article.

Comment: @user3169 Hmm, I'd say that my last sentence meets that question about as head-on as it can be met. Still, I'll add a line higher up.